# basic trouble opening a file with python object oriented programming script

Tags: python, oop, sys

I'm new to OOP and am having trouble writing and executing a basic script that will open and read a file.

I'm getting an error `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '--profile-dir'` when I run this. What's wrong with this and how should I fix it?

```
class testing(object):

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.words = self.file_to_text()

    def file_to_text(self):
        with open(filename, "r") as file_opened:
            text = file_opened.read()
            words = text.split()
            return words

alice = testing("alice.txt").file_to_text()
print alice
```

Also, if I'd like to be able to make this executable from the command line, these tweaks should make it work, right?

```
import sys
...
alice = testing(sys.argv[1]).file_to_text()
print alice

line to actually input in command line to run it-----> ./testing.py alice.txt
```

thanks in advance guys.

Comment: where is `'--profile-dir'` coming from?

Comment: In `file_to_text`, replace `filename` with `self.filename` and `words` with `self.words` so that it sets those variables on the class instance and not as locals (though that's unrelated to the error message you're getting).

Comment: @PadraicCunningham sorry Padraic, I see that in the error message, but what does that mean?

Comment: So you're _already_ running it from the CLI, aren't you?

Comment: @heltonbiker im writing it and testing in ipython notebook but want to make it executable from the CLI as well.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo - those fixes actually made it work! why did you think that wouldn't fix it?

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce I turned the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere you have a `filename =  '--profile-dir'` defined, that is being used in  `with open(filename, "r")`, use  `with open(self.filename, "r")` to use the actual attribute you have defined in the class:

```
filename = "foob"
class testing(object):  
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.words = self.file_to_text()
    def file_to_text(self):
        print(filename)
        with open(filename, "r") as file_opened:
            text = file_opened.read()
            words = text.split()
            return words
```

Output:

```
foob
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'foob'
```

Your code will work fine using sys.argv once you make the  change:

```
import sys

class testing(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.words = self.file_to_text()
    def file_to_text(self):
        with open(self.filename, "r") as file_opened:
            text = file_opened.read()
            words = text.split()
            return words
alice = testing(sys.argv[1]).file_to_text()
print alice

:~$ python main.py input.txt
['testing']
```

If you want to use `./` put `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top and `chmod +x` to make it executable.

You can also avoid calling read and splitting using itertools.chain:

```
from itertools import chain
class testing(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.words = self.file_to_text()
    def file_to_text(self):
        with open(self.filename, "r") as file_opened:
            return list(chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in file_opened))
```

Comment: Thanks Padraic. What about the sys.argv part of the question to make it executable from the CLI?

Comment: can you elaborate on why the `self.words` is used in the first example but not the second and vice versa for `self.filename`?

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce, you don't need self.words. `self.words = self.file_to_text()` is assigning `self.words` to the return value of the method

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(filename, "r") as file_opened:
```

This reads from a *global variable* named `filename`, not the one that you set in your initializer. Presumably, it has the value `'--profile-dir'`, so it tries to open a file with that name and throws an error when it doesn't exist. You want to replace `filename` with `self.filename` to get the field in the class instance.

Answer (score 0):

1. The error may be because of the arguments that are passed to the script, search for `--profile-dir` in the run configuration settings and remove it.
2. To pass the arguments from the command line, append the code below to your script

   `if __name__ == '__main__':
         if len(sys.argv) > 1:
             alice = testing(sys.argv[1]).file_to_text()`

Comment: hey @Bharadwaj, how would i search for that in the run config settings?

Comment: What IDE are you using for Python development?

Comment: just using ipython notebook.

Comment: While running the script, what commands do you use? `%run %Option` what is the `Option` here

Answer (score 0):

This code uses linecache and reads any line that you want, without really opening the file. It is fast!

```
import linecache

class Read_Line(object):
    def __init__(self, file_input, line):
        self.file_input = file_input
        self.line = line

    def Line_to_Text(self):
        Words = linecache.getline(self.file_input, self.line)
        Words = Words.split()
        return Words

Test = Read_Line("File.txt", 3)
print Test.Line_to_Text()
```